# PTIJ: Who is Chaya in the Megillah?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

In Esther ([4:11](https://www.sefaria.org/Esther.4.11?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi)), we find that anyone, "man or woman, [who] enters the king’s presence in the inner court without having been summoned" is to be put to death -- with only two exceptions:

> לְבַד מֵאֲשֶׁר יוֹשִׁיט־לוֹ הַמֶּלֶךְ אֶת־שַׁרְבִיט הַזָּהָב, וְחָיָה
>
> Excepting [the person] to whom the the king extends the golden
> scepter, and Chaya.

**Who is Chaya, and what is so special about her?**

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 2):

In the Babylonian religion, which the Persian Empire kept, Chaya was one the gods they worshipped in their pantheon. See:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haya_(god)

The law was that, on the off chance that this god materialized in the king's court (which of course never happened), he was automatically allowed in.

Comment: It doesnt say they were allowed in only they werent killed if they came in see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This Chaya was one of the descendants of Minna who was on Noah's ark as it says:

Breishit 7:14:

הֵ֜מָּה וְכָל־הַֽחַיָּ֣ה לְמִינָ֗הּ

Them and all the Chaya's belonging to Minna.

I understand that Minna was one of a kind!

Answer (score -1):

In chumash this word is  in the possuk about the girls pharaoh let live. (Although with a different gender than here, but now we are saying it is the same feminine gender according to the question) It must be  this possuk in the megila  is referring to those girls that pharaoh kept alive. The baal haturim on the torah says this type of think often. That two the same words in the mesora have a connection. And that is the simple connection here, they are the same girls or had a similar characteristic .So now we know who the chaya in the megilla is being  referred to as an exception of not being killed.  One must now find a reason why the king 'excepted' them from this rule. Everyone was to be killed except girls called chaya.
Maybe he was 'scared' to kill them since pharaoh must also have had some unknown reason not to kill them, most likely he was scared to, so Achashverosh was also scared to.

Comment: The midwives did answer Pharaoh that they are like animals. And the female is deadlier than the male (kipling), so although he could kill the males but not the deadly females.